# Am I using Distinct incorrectly?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of strings and I want to parse it down to unique values. I thought after I step through the distinct method it should have two value, but it still has the original 1001. Clearly it's not having the effect I'm trying to achieve. My question is, am I using this method incorrectly, or am I misunderstanding the purpose of the method.

```
List<string> theAddressTypes = new List<string>();

Dictionary<string, string> addressTypeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (CustomerRow customer in theCustomerData)
{
    theAddressTypes.Add(customer.AddressType);
}

foreach (string value in theAddressTypes.Distinct())
{
    SqlCommand insertAddressType = new SqlCommand("Insert into AddressType Values ('" + value + "'); Select SCOPE_IDENTITY();", 
    newCustConnection);
    string addressTypeId = insertAddressType.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    addressTypeDictionary.Add(addressTypeId, value);
}

return addressTypeDictionary;
```

Comment: Why don't you check the values when adding? You could use theAddressTypes.Contains(customer.AddressType) before adding all the address types just to filter the unique ones afterwards?

Comment: Have you overriden the equals method on the AddressType class? If the addresstype class is a reference object then the equals method would only be comparing if they are the same object

Comment: If you're using .Net 3.5 or greater you might look at HashSet<T>. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Distinct` will return a collection where none are repeated. It uses the `IEquatable` to check if two objects are the same.

Your code could be simplified to.

```
List<string> theAddressTypes = (from customer in theCustomerData select customer.AddressType).Distinct().ToList();
```

You're not defining any column names in your SQL insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

The Distinct method returns a new list, it doesn't change the original list. This is probably the reason you're thinking it's not working.

Comment: He's using the `Distinct()` method in a `foreach`.

Comment: @Bob. Yes he is, so how does he know it still has all 1001 entries? His code is correct, there's no possible way it's doing what he says. He says after he steps through the Distinct call it still has 1001 entries, which it will anyway, he misunderstands what happens with that call as I said.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're viewing the original source and not the `IEnumerable` created by `Distinct`.
`Distinct` works *as you're enumerating* the `IEnumerable` so you're code is fine but not as concise as it could be.

```
Dictionary<string, string> addressTypeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (string value in theCustomerData.Select(c => c.AddressType).Distinct())
{
    string addressTypeId = InsertAddressType(value);
    addressTypeDictionary.Add(addressTypeId, value);
}

return addressTypeDictionary;

...

private string InsertAddressType(string value)
{
    // read up on SQL Injection and do this safely
    using (var newCustConnection = new SqlConnection(...))
    using (var insertAddressType = new SqlCommand("Insert into AddressType Values (@addressTypeValue); Select SCOPE_IDENTITY();", 
    newCustConnection))
    {
        // set parameter value first
        return insertAddressType.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
}
```

You could probably do this as a one-liner but doing so really hides the fact you have side effects whereas it sticks out above (a `foreach` when reading LINQ code usually highlights the fact that side effects are occurring):

```
return (from addressType in theCustomerData.Select(c => c.AddressType).Distinct()
        let id = InsertAddressType(addressType) // side effect here
        select new {id, addressType})
      .ToDictionary(o => o.id, o => o.addressType);
```

[MSDN Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)